# how to run unoconv command directly from windows command prompt

Tags: python, windows, laravel, unoconv

I am trying to use unoconv for file conversion

I have downloaded LibreOffice and added 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program` , path where `python.exe`, `pyuno.pyd` and `soffice.exe` resides, to system path variable, so that when I run `C:\Users\user> python` its working

I also downlaoded `Unoconv` zip from https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv
extracted it and placed the folder inside `C:\Program Files (x86)`, so that the `unoconv` files is located here `C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master`

Now in the command prompt when I run
`C:\Users\user > python unoconv -h`,

I get this error
`C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\\python-core-3.3.0: can't open file 'unoconv' : [Error 2] No such fiel or directory`

but when I navigate to unoconv folder and run the same command

`C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master > python unoconv -h` it works fine,

I have also added `C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master` in system path variable and created a `UNO_PATH` variable with `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program`

**how to run the `python unoconv -h` command from any location, without navigating to unoconv folder?**

**Update:** Actually I am working on a larvel application and trying to use `unoconv`, for this, along with above setup have used `php-unoconv` library https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-Unoconv, but when running the basic code given in docs of php-unoconv I get the below error

```
ExecutableNotFoundException in AbstractBinary.php line 160: Executable not found, proposed : unoconv
```

how to fix this error ? I thought it must be something to do with system environment variable, if not then any idea on why I am getting this error

Comment: Run `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"` to see the directories it searches. Is there a `site-packages` directory in there? Try adding a `unoconv.pth` text file with a single line: `C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master`. If a .pth file doesn't work for you, add the directory to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. It's best to do this in a batch file that sets up the working environment, as opposed to setting `PYTHONPATH` permanently.

Comment: yes I got the `site-packages` directory, added `unoconv.pth` file and also tried with `unoconv.pth.txt` file, but still getting the same error in terminal. Also added `C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master` to `PYTHONPATH` environment variable but its still the same

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that you need `-m`, for example `python -m unoconv`, when running a package from `sys.path` as a script.

Comment: tried this `python -m unoconv -h` an dgot this `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program\python-core-3.3.0\bin\python.exe: No module named unoconv`

Comment: I assume this was with a .pth file or the directory in `PYTHONPATH`? Try just running python to get the interactive shell. Then do `import sys` and `sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\unoconv-master')`. The try `import unoconv` and `dir(unoconv)`.